# Using dplyr to select a range based on a grouping variable in a separate data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to slice up a `data.frame` containing an irregularly sampled time series based on a grouping factor and a range of time slices in a separate `data.frame`. I'm doing this with a loop now in a really inelegant way. I've been trying to get better with tidy syntax and wondering if there is a more elegant approach to get `res` from `foo` and `bar`.

```
foo <- data.frame(x=seq(1,100,by=2),y=rnorm(n=50)) 
# foo$x would actually be less regular in the real data
bar <- data.frame(ID=c("Stage_1","Stage_2","Stage_3","Stage_4"),
                  xMin = c(10,32,54,85),
                  xMax = c(17,50,76,89))
res <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:nlevels(bar$ID)){
  xMin <- bar$xMin[bar$ID==levels(bar$ID)[i]]
  xMax <- bar$xMax[bar$ID==levels(bar$ID)[i]]

  xMinIndex <- findInterval(xMin,foo$x) #could fuss inner and outer search
  xMaxIndex <- findInterval(xMax,foo$x)

  tmp <- foo[xMinIndex:xMaxIndex,]
  tmp$ID <- levels(bar$ID)[i]
  res <- rbind(res,tmp)
}
res
```

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `Map`

```
res1 <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y, z) 
   data.frame(foo[x:y,], ID = as.character(z), stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
     findInterval(bar$xMin, foo$x),
        findInterval(bar$xMax, foo$x), bar$ID))
all.equal(res1, res)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(foo)[bar,  on = .(x >= xMin, x <= xMax)]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
bar %>% 
    transmute(ID, col1 = map2(findInterval(xMin, foo$x),  
                               findInterval(xMax, foo$x),  ~
                         foo %>% slice(.x:.y))) %>% 
    unnest(c(col1))
```

Comment: Wow. I've been using R since 2001 and have never seen Map before. I need to wrap my brain around it.